# Finding the Components of a Hessian Matrix of a Quadratic Form

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to find the Hessian form of the following quadratic form: $f(x,y) = x^2y+y^2+xy$. I know that it's in the form of a matrix and that the elements  of $H_f(a)_{i,j}$ are $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$.

I have no problem with finding the elements of the diagonal, but how do I find the elements $H_f(a)_{1,2}$ for example. I know that it's $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y} $.

Do we have the following equality:  $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$? Or do I need to proceed differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2xy+y$$
$$\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg)=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg(2xy+y\bigg)=2x+1$$
And
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x^2+2y+x$$
$$\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial y \partial x}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\bigg(x^2+2y+x\bigg)=2x+1$$